# On the new User Profile screen, why can't I link my Stack Overflow Careers account?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs, user-accounts

On the new profile screen (I just noticed it today), I am unable to link my careers account, even though I have had one for a couple of years. I see this instead (screenshot included):

> No Careers profile for this account; click the link to find out more!

[image: what I see]

Clicking the link opens Careers, and I am already logged in. How can I link these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is some disconnect here - not sure why the profile isn't found initially. Something for me to look at.

But - there is a work around:

On Careers, toggle your CV to private then back to public. Give it about 10 seconds and refresh your profile edit page on Stack Overflow.

**Edit**: This issue should now be resolved

Comment: Thank you! This simple work-around did the trick :smile:

Comment: Hey @Oded, I had the same issue and this workaround also worked for me.

Comment: @PeterGrace I don't see any option to toggle the visibility of my CV on SO Careers

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez - you can see it on your profile (in the "Edit Profile & Settings" section - go to the bottom of that page to the "Show Careers link on my profile" checkbox - make sure it is checked.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue; I've tried changing the privacy settings several times, including some waiting time between and after changing them. Still not fixed.

Comment: @Oded I'm having almost the same issue— the careers link works on SO & SO Meta but not on any other SE site.  The Public->Private->Public solution didn't work for me.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson - it is an SO/MSO only feature

Comment: Hmm.  Then why does it show the _“No Careers profile for this account; click the link to find out more!”/“Discover Stack Overflow Careers”/“Once you create a Careers profile, come back here to display it”_ messages when editing my profile on every other site?

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson - something may have changed. Will need to look into that.

Comment: @Oded: Cheers. ;-)

Comment: Confirmed that this should only appear on SO/MSO, so the bug is that the section shows up on all sites. I will be fixing today, @SlippD.Thompson