# "No Careers profile for this account"

Tags: bug, jobs, profile-page

In the user profile settings, there is a "web presence" section which allows linking to (amongst other things) a Careers profile; however, in my case it's empty and can't be edited, although I actually *have* a Careers profile, and it's correctly accessed if I click on the "Discover Stack Overflow Careers" link:

[image]

Is this a bug? How can I fix it?

---

Update: I have the same issue on ***all*** network sites... except on StackOverflow; there, everything seems to work as it should:

[image]

Comment: Known bug. As [this answer says](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253531/152859), changing privacy settings from public to private and back to public solve this.

Comment: I've tried two times, including some waiting time between and after changing settings. Still not fixed.

Comment: So I fear we'll have to wait for a dev to look into it.

Comment: For the record, since the Jobs beta on Stack Overflow, all Careers bugs get more attention on MSO - you might have better luck posting in there, and deleting this report here.

Comment: I originally posted on MSF... the question has been migrated.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed. Looks like the SF mods are still not aware of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312744/is-the-careers-meta-going-to-move-from-mse-to-mso) then.

Comment: I still can't understand if this whole "jobs" thing will be directed only to developers (more than it is now, anyway), and what plans are there (if any) for a ServerFault counterpart for sysadmins...

Comment: Can't say I understand or agree, but you might find some insights [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better).